# How can you flip website upside down in IE ? (for the April 1st)

Tags: javascript, html, css

We are making April 1st prank in our office, and wanted to flip our corporate website upside down for several hours tomorrow :)

My patch works everywhere but not in IE... Can anyone help ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.body.style.MozTransform = 'rotate(180deg)';
   document.body.style['-webkit-transform'] = 'rotate(180deg)';
</script>
```

Comment: Any quick way to apply this across all pages in Chrome?  Would be great prank on my wife.  :-D

Comment: @loneboat: Use extension [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) + `body { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); }` should be a fairly quick way to do it.

Comment: Found an easy answer:  INstall the Chrome extension "Stylish", and add a single rule across all websites:  body { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); }  EDIT:  Thanks thirtydot!

Comment: For anyone who wants to play a local practical joke, many Dell and other computers will flip the screen by hitting control, alt, and arrow (for right, left, up, or down)  Often, this setting can also be tweaked on the graphics card settings.  Makes for great fun with non-techie people.

Comment: Found another cool thing, that could be done:  http://www.ex-parrot.com/pete/upside-down-ternet.html

Comment: All of these answers are not good in IE if there are layers with "position: absolute". IE is wicked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A slightly simpler version for IE (no matrix stuff):

```
body {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533014(VS.85,loband).aspx

Comment: That's the one, though using it is no easy matter :).

Answer (score 7):

Your CSS is specific to webkit and firefox.

You will need to use [-ms-transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ff468705#_CSS3_2D_Transforms) in IE9, otherwise check out [this link](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/) for other versions of IE

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: This doesn't work.

Try

```
body {
     -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);  
       -o-transform: rotate(180deg);  
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);  
      -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);  
          transform: rotate(180deg);  
             filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix( 
                     M11=-1, M12=-1.2246063538223773e-16, M21=1.2246063538223773e-16, M22=-1, sizingMethod='auto expand');
               zoom: 1;
}
```

Demo: http://static.arounds.org/moz.html

Generated with: http://css3please.com/

Comment: Demo link is broken now